# Github and Gitlab Connection

Tags: git

I have a repo with many commits already on gitlab but when I created a repo with another name on github and push those same files and started working on github repo and pushes changes on it 
It shows the commit on gitlab too ..
How to delete those commits from gitlab 
and What If I delete the github repo will gitlab repo will be also deleted ???

Comment: I think you need to give more information here.  How are you pushing your repo?  From where?  Are you sure those commits are showing up in GitLab too?  How do you know that?  Commits shouldn't magically show up, so you're either pushing them there somehow or they're being pulled in by something.

Comment: Also are the commits you want to remove all on one branch?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 0):

## Mirror the Whole Repo

First, the best way to mirror the repo is not to simply push one branch to the new repo but to mirror the whole thing:

```
git clone --mirror git@gitlab.com:project/repo.git
cd repo.git
git push --mirror git@github.com:project/repo.git

# Don't need bare repo.git anymore... discard it.
cd ..
rm -rf repo.git
```

Next, you set up a new working tree by cloning the new repo:

```
git clone git@github.com:project/repo.git
```

As long as you have not set up anything special, once you do this your commits will only go to GitHub.  Why?  Because that's the only remote.

## "Mirror" by Pushing Master

If your goal is to use your existing working copy and only push master but you also want to disconnect GitLab, then you'll need to do something like this inside your existing working tree:

```
git checkout master
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:project/repo.git
git push origin master
git push --tags
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master

# To repopulate your remotes area...
git fetch --all
```

Note a few things here: you need to be careful about adding your remotes.  You can actually push to more than one url for a remote.  You can see how your remotes are setup with `git remote -v` and you should see something like:

```
:: git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:project/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:project/repo.git (push)
```

If you see that origin has more than one push url, then that may be how commits are showing up in GitLab.

## Fixing GitLab

To be honest, there's not enough information in your post to really answer this part of the question.  However, let's say there are a few extra commits on master in GitLab that you don't want and that you're working from a normal clone (*not* a `--bare` or `--mirror` clone).  If you're currently at commit `def456` and you really want `abc123` to be the tip of master, you can force push the new tip.  I don't really recommend this without understanding what you are doing because **you can lose history by doing this**.  The idea is this:

```
git push --force git@gitlab.com:project/repo.git abc123:master
```

I used the url form of a remote here (instead of a name, like origin) because I really don't know the state of your tree--you have far too little information in your question.  The above says go to the repo at `git@gitlab.com:project/repo.git` and make its master branch be `abc123`.

This kind of answer really leaves out a lot of details--you might have commits in other branches that you don't want, tags you don't want, we have no clue given your question.

Personally, I think if you can leave it alone, then you should.  It sounds like you're still coming up to speed on Git and the risk of harm is greater than the benefit, IMHO.  If you really want to fix it, I suggest starting another question and provide all the details (show your remotes, the output of `git ls-remote` would be useful, along with a full description of what branches need to be at what commits, and don't forget if there are tags that need to be removed too... we really have no idea what you have done).